# How to know whether a model is feasible

Tags: c#, gurobi

I am using C# api. Given a gurobi model

```
GRBModel model = new GRBModel(env);
```

after populating constraint, giving objective function, and doing

```
model.Optimize();
```

is there a way to determine whether the model is feasible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the [optimization status code](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/5.0/reference-manual/node740) after solving the model.  In most cases, you simply need to test that the status is `OPTIMAL`.  For an example, see `mip2_cs.cs` in the `examples\c#` subdirectory.